# Call JavaScript function from JavaFX before loading

Tags: javascript, javafx, javafx-webengine

I need to initialize some variables in JavaScript from JavaFX WebEngine before actually loading the html file. My .html file looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var a;
        function setA(aa) {
            a = aa;
        }
        function f() {
            <!-- ... some operation with var a-->
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='f();'>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

And for the JavaFX part:

```
 @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException {
        WebView webview = new WebView();
        WebEngine webengine=webview.getEngine();

        // Set var a before webengine.load
        webengine.load(getClass().getResource("hello.html").toString());

        Pane p = new Pane();
        p.getChildren().add(webview);
        Scene scene = new Scene(p);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

I tried not putting onload='f();' in body tag of the .html, and then I tried calling JavaScript functions one by one from Java like this:

```
webengine.load(getClass().getResource("hello.html").toString());
webengine.executeScript("setA(123)");
webengine.executeScript("f()");
```

but this doesn't work (I get ReferenceError: Can't find variable setA/f ).

Any potential solutions?

Comment: What exactly is your goal? From what I understand, you need to initialize some state before your html gets loaded. What you could do is generate the html file first using a template library (like Freemarker). This way you can set the state beforehand, then load your (now stateful) generated html file in JavaFX.

Comment: I actually thought about doing something similar, but I thought there was an easier way. To be exact, I'm using Bing Maps JavaScript API and I want to load map centered on some coordinates that I get during the execution of the JavaFX program. I have JavaScript function that loads the map with predefined coordinates, and I need to set those coordinates just before the page loads. I have basically no experience with JavaScript so I'm sorry if my question isn't adequate in any way. Thank you for your reply @BillTsagkas

Comment: Do you execute the scripts immediately after the `webengine.load()` method? Have you tried executing them after the page has been loaded? (by using a `ChangeListener` on `webengine`'s load worker) - Check [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) in documentation. I tried executing your code that way, by executing the scripts on page _load_. The desired result was shown on page _render_. Can you try that and come back with the results?

Comment: I've tried that method earlier and it didn't work (for God knows what reason), but I tried it again now and it works perfectly.  Thank you very much @BillTsagkas!

Answer (score -1):

So you want to execute some js stuff before the "browser" start processing the html content...

Short answer... you can't really do that.

Long answer... you can actually do that, but you'll need to either use a locally modified version of the jdk in which you modify hidden components such as WebPage which is a compoment used by WebEngine ... or use reflection to bypass runtime access policies... but even so, it opens up a can of worms and you'll have no guarantee it will work the way you expect it.